# NET5.0 PublishSingleFile publish more than one file

Tags: publish, .net-5, single-file

I'm publishing my net 5 app with:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true
```

but, as a result I have:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/16/2021  10:20 PM         747896 clrcompression.dll
-a----        2/16/2021  10:20 PM        1322360 clrjit.dll
-a----        2/16/2021  10:20 PM        5153144 coreclr.dll
-a----        3/15/2021  11:48 AM       53841260 fff.exe
-a----        3/15/2021  11:48 AM          11300 fff.pdb
-a----        3/15/2021  11:48 AM            537 fff.xml
-a----        2/16/2021  10:20 PM        1056640 mscordaccore.dll
```

deploying just fff.exe does not work. Have to deploy dll's too. Why?
Source code for reference can be found here: [Fast Find in Files](https://github.com/FelicePollano/FFF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -c release
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#other-considerations)

Answer (score 2):

> deploying just fff.exe does not work. Have to deploy dll's too. Why?

To answer your actual question... Here are the reasons why there are more files that fff.exe:

- `coreclr.dll` contains the native libraries of the dotnet core framework.
- `clrjit.dll` contains the just in time compiler of the dotnet core framework
- `clrcompression.dll` contains native data compression routines.
- `*.pdb` contains debug symbols. You can omit them in release builds.
- `*.xml` contains summaries (descriptions of classes, methods, etc)

Like @JL0PD already mentioned. To achieve your desired result, just use this command to publish your application:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true -c release
```