# Visual Studio 2019/.NET 5: Compiling Single Project with No Dependencies Creates Application DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I moved from from VS15 to VS19 with a new laptop, and my new project is a single Windows Forms project that will go on the client's server to pull metrics, stats, and some other info and generate an output file they send back. The requirement is for it to be a single EXE.

However, with all my code in one project, and no dependencies outside .NET itself, I'm getting [application].exe and [application].dll. This is not acceptable, and I cannot find an option that disables this.

Does anyone know where this is, or do I have to go back to VS 2015?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why "this is not accepable" ?

Comment: Aside from being completely unnecessary, it removes control on how I want my projects published. In this specific case, it's unreasonable to force multiple clients to fumble with multiple unnecessary files, when the point of this project is simplicity/ease of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the new normal for .NET Core / .NET 5: the .exe is a wrapper that starts the .NET run time, and all your application code is in the .dll.

You have two options:

- You can go back to .NET Framework 4.x (no need to downgrade VS for that -- you can use VS2019 with C# 9 targeting .NET 4.x)
- You can look into .NET 5 [single-file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio). Note that this will require the "Publish" step to generate the single file; the normal result of the "Build" step will still be .exe+.dll.

  - You can use a "Framework-dependent" publish to avoid including the .NET runtime with your application (this avoids the separate native runtime dlls)
  - Or you could use `/p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true` to force the native runtime dlls to be included in the .exe file.

Comment: Regular single file publish will place several assemblies nearby. If you want to produce exactly one file, read this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66760154/net5-0-publishsinglefile-publish-more-than-one-file/

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I now also have several .net dlls in the build folder as well. I was planning on ignoring these, because the target machines will have .net already...but if these are now required for the exe to run, this is even worse. I'm pretty disappointed with VS19 and .NET5 overall, so I might as well wipe this laptop and start over.